# I’d like to know how to ship is it

Tags: sentence-construction

is it right sentence?

> I’d like to know how to ship is it

I want to say "I want to know shipping method"

Comment: My guess would be "how to ship it," but the context isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good phrase

> "I want to know [the] shipping method"

You should use "the". This is a correct way to ask your question.

Or

> I’d like to know how to ship <s>is</s> it.

The word "is" is wrong.    "how to ship it" is the object. I can build the sentence like this

> "I know (something)" -> "I know how to ship it." ->  "I'd like to know how to ship it"

Answer (score 0):

Either **I'd like to know how to ship it** or **I want to know the shipping method** I think. I am quite certain that either of those would work. Also, welcome :) I am new here too and I am happy to meet you :)